# Linux Live does't boot

Tags: linux, boot, formatting

I'm trying to make a persistent bootable linux OS (via a usb flash-drive), but it fails to boot.

I made a non-persistent Linux Live (ubuntu 18.04) awhile ago, and because I don't understand much in hardware-software issues, and about formatting problems I already know, I got myself another flash-drive. first, I've tried making a persistent image using the newest image of ubuntu (18.04), using mkusb, on the non-persistent OS. It showed an error (which I haven't documented) while making the device, and finished the process. The new flash-drive didn't boot.

Iv'e formatted the usb device using windows 10 cmd window, following the steps of the following article (excluding the 'quick') -

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10

this attempt, like the rest of the attempts was in the FAT32 format, which is the standard bootable devices, as such as this one.

iv'e tried making a persistent image using the Rufus formatting tool, but Iv'e used cluster size of 16kb, which after farther research, I realized, was too small for persistent image (the other configurations were MBR, FAT32).

As I rebooted the device, the 'try ubuntu' etc. menu appeared, and no matter which option I've selected. I got the following error:

```
[Firmware Bug]: Failed to parse event in TPM Final Events Log
```

I've re-formatted the device using the cmd window, and then I've tried rufus, with the GPT partition, and for the obvious reason GPT doesn't boot, I've formatted, I've changed the partition to MBR, and re-formatted the USB flash-drive (through cmd, again).

After some self research, I learned that 16kb and forward cluster size, is for non-persistent. Hence, iv'e formatted the device using the 'Computer Management' formatting option (FAT32 & non-quick) and iv'e tried 8192 bytes cluster size, and thought iv'e probably solved the problem. I rebooted, and for every selected choice from the ubuntu menu, the usual error got replaced with another one, and the device refused to boot. I haven't listed the error, but if relevant i'll reboot from the device, and edit this post and add it.

What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this problem and boot from a persistent flash-drive?

Comment: One software (free) for Windows does that very well, because it'll let you decide how much space on your USB stick you want to dedicate to persistence: https://www.linuxliveusb.com/ . The interface is somewhat colorful, but it does what it says, quickly and without fuss. Works with mostly all available Linux distros around, 32-bit and 64-bit alike.

Comment: While researching for a solution to the problem i mentioned, i learned about the different tools including the one you've mentioned. As for iv'e used the more advanced tool (Rufus) correctly, and it failed to boot, probaly trying linuxliveusb wouldn't work as well

Comment: It's worth a try anyway. I've seen that on several occasions: Rufus is fast, but not always thorough when it comes to write bootable USB sticks. Linux Live USB was specifically designed for that: making bootable USB sticks and drives for Linux distributions. I don't have a dog in this race, it's up to you, but if you want to try a Linux Live distro AND get persistence on your stick, you should try it. My two cents.

Comment: Well, iv'e used linuxliveusb, and althrough the system booted, it booted as non-persistent. Althrough iv'e setted it up to the maximal persistent (4090mb) possible in the tool (it's a 32gb usb stick, and i'll be glad to be able to use all of it). While, messages which indicated the correct formatting proccess appeared, so i guess it's a reliable tool for this specifiec porpuse. How do i make it persistent? Now i officialy own two non-persistent live ubuntu usb sticks.

Comment: Does your PC have a BIOS or UEFI? It's important, because for some reason, persistence on UEFI machines requires a modification in the /EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg file to add "persistent" (no quotes) at the end of each line that starts with "linux" (or "Linux"). Worth a try. You can open that file with any text editor, but be sure to save it with its original extension.

Answer (score 0):

My PC is using BIOS. Iv'e opened the ubuntu 'Disks' utillity, and the usb stick shows one partition only. Is there a way to make a second partition designated as persistent storage area, through the non-persistent live OS? No other solution comes to my head

Comment: Either way, you can try to add the "persistent" argument, preceded by a space, to the end of each line starting with "linux" (there should be three: linux16.mod, linuxefi.mod and linux.mod), save the file with its .cfg extension (be careful not to add a .txt at the end, or your stick won't boot at all), and try to reboot on it. Persistent storage will be created (or should...) upon starting up on the stick.

Comment: Problem Solved. Iv'e opened the grub.cfg file, added the word persistent, closed it down under the right format, and as far as i can tell, my ubuntu is now persistent.

Comment: Well, enjoy your Linux live, then! Cheers mate!

Comment: is there an alternative way to make a persistent live Linux? It worked, it was persistent, i was happy and prepared for a productive day of work on my Linux OS, and then it refused to boot. Iv'e formatted it, made it persistent, it worked, and then it failed to boot. Iv'e done it accouple of times, pretty much going in circles.

Comment: When you say "it worked", what do you mean? That you managed to boot on it once, and then no more, or that you got no error message after copying files on it, but no boot? Have you ensured that the stick is bootable? Can you try it on another computer, preferably one that doesn't share the same specs as yours?

Comment: Saying it worked, i meant the system booted, saved every single change iv'e done, and saved every installation of softwares, files, and personal configuration of the system. After restarting, again and again, the system remained persistent, and everything was saved. And suddenly, trying to turn on from the bootable usb stick, the system refused to boot, giving an error message. Im using a high quality SanDisk, I have only one PC, and it is my DELL laptop, which is new, powerfull, and has very good specs.

Comment: What's the error message say? If it booted OK several times in a row and then suddenly stopped booting, then something must have changed, either in your setup on the PC, or on the SanDisk USB thingy you boot from. Or both.

Comment: Althrough its a different scenario than the mentioned in the original issue, the PC issued the same error message mentioned. [Firmware Bug]: Failed to parse event in TPM Final Events Log

Comment: TPM stands for Trusted Platform Module. That's a passive security solution set in an embedded chip on your motherboard. Your PC was designed to run Windows and little else. Dell does produce Linux-equipped or -compatible PC, but not all of them are. You can go into your UEFI/BIOS and either disable TPM if you can (not sure you can), or reset it. That should be in the Security tab of your UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: Good idea. I dont see TPM in my boot settings, under the security tab. Iv'e got 'PPT security' tab, which seems generic to the TPM. There's also 'SMM Security Mittigation'. I'll turn my usb stick to persistent, wait for it to stop functioning, and then try the different options. If there's an obvious solution, i'll be glad to know it, before i'll start checking a windows ment PC boot settings, which is usually not to good of an idea.

Comment: As I said, it's a passive security solution, i.e. one that can't be configured by the user. It's there to prevent data theft and boot corruption by branding each component and peripheral with a UID (Unique IDentifier) that's specific to each machine. The downside is, you can't change a major component like a HDD or RAM bus without resetting TPM in the BIOS, otherwise the PC won't boot. On the upside, there are solutions to boot Linux distros in spite of TPM. See here, for example: https://paolozaino.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/configure-and-use-your-tpm-module-on-linux/